# unable to get the correct data from database

Tags: java, struts2

I have written code for getting data from my database.

When users click a link then the below action is called.  It gives me correct data for first time  .But  if admin updates the table data . Then the below code fails to show the newly updated data from the table.  if i refresh the page many times then it shows newly updated data. But again after next refresh it shows the old data.

i am very sure the problem is with the dao or may be in Action class.  I don't know what is the problem behind this?
Please help me to solve this issue.

BookdetailsDAO.java

```
    public   List findasc(int o,int l)
{
     List list = null;

        try {
             session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession(); 
             Query q1 = session.createQuery("FROM Bookdetails  ORDER BY authLastname ASC");
             q1.setFirstResult(o);
             q1.setMaxResults(l); 
            list =q1.list(); 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception in  findasc()  :" + e);
        } finally {
            try {
                 session.flush();
                session.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception In findasc Resource closing  :" + e);
            }
        } 
        return list; 
}
```

Comment: have you tried with editor debug mode? are you using any kind of caching?

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi Sorry but i don't know about editor debug mode? I know only eclipse debugger or using `System.out.print("");` . i do'nt understand the meaning of `are you using any kind of caching?`

Comment: Yes i am talking about Eclipse Debug mode, try that to see where is the issue and i believe it is either at Hibernate side where its returning you cached data and not firing any database query,try to enable hibernate logging and see what exactly is going on

Comment: Where is your transaction demarcation? Looks like the query result is being cached. Can you show your Hibernate setting? ... Also the way that you are declaring all those variables make your code very unreadable. Don't declare them until you need them, and declare them in the smallest scope possible (e.g. you could do `int id = bookobj.getId();`).

Comment: @BheshGurung i updated. please check it my above

Comment: Why are you not beginning and committing transaction? Try adding that.

Comment: @BheshGurung  
i tried using `Transaction tx=session.beginTransaction();` and then `tx.commit();` . But still sometime it shows old data. Same Problem.

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi I tried as you said. But still i could not solve my problem. Please check whether my code is wrong or something else. I found that the problem is in DAO only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a dedicated commit instead of the flush. Probably Hibernate does not commit instantly when you close the session.

You should also try reading all data in one transaction. According to your code, you open a session for every single call to the DAO. Re-use the session for calls that belong together.

I strongly recommend letting your infrastructure do the session opening, closing and committing for you. Consider using an annotation driven approach e.g.

Comment: Thank you! but I didn't  understand clearly what you explain. Can you show some code with reference to your explanation?   `You should also try reading all data in one transaction. According to your code, you open a session for every single call to the DAO. Re-use the session for calls that belong together.`???

Comment: That link explains pretty much what you want to do.  In particular, it shows how to have one session per request.

Comment: Particularly interesting for you is section 'Transaction demarcation with plain JDBC'

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by applying this code

`sessionFactory.close();
                tx.commit();

                session.close();`

Comment: Why did you accept your own answer when sorencito's was earlier and said to use a commit, which is what you're doing?

Comment: i accepted because `sessionFactory.close();` is the main solution of my problem. sorencito did not said about to do `sessionFactory.close();`  . i did litle googling and got the solution. But you said to accept  sorencito answer, so now i accepted his answer.